# Remove git integrations from VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I downloaded Visual Studio Code to try out at work and I'm in love with almost everything about it. One part I am not in love with though: Git integration.

I imported my entire working folder (~14000 source files + git items), and the layout and everything within Visual Studio Code is awesome. I moved from our traditional code editor to this, because it seemed to work a lot better for me.

My main issue though, is if I am working in a file and save it, Visual Studio Code freezes up for roughly 30-60 seconds. At first I was confused, but then I noticed that the Git tab was "working." From my best guess, after I save a file it is traversing all ~14000 files and doing something - I'm not sure what.
Does anyone know if there is a way to remove Git integration from VSC, or at least have it ignore doing whatever it thinks it is doing?

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Add this to `settings.json`:

```
// Whether git is enabled.
"git.enabled": false,
```

Some other commands related to Git execution:

```
// Path and filename of the git executable, e.g. `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe` (Windows).
"git.path": null,

// When enabled, commits will automatically be fetched from the default remote of the current Git repository.
"git.autofetch": false,
```

Comment: Just the git.enabled part did the trick for me, was there a reason to add the other two options?

Comment: It seems setting only `"git.enabled" = false` option is just enough.

Comment: Where is `settings.json` supposed to be on macOS?

Comment: `cmd + ,` or `Code > Preferences > Settings` bring up settings on MacOS.

Comment: @msdos Thanks, this should be the default setting in my opinion, that popup is aggravating to say the least.

Comment: only set git.autofetch to false if you still want to use the git integration on VSC

Comment: I tried it on version 1.19 and though I copied all of them after launch it still looks for GIT installation. Any idea?

Comment: i have svn extension installed but when opens the project it showing source control as GIT, then i disabled GIT after this it showing no source control provider registered. am i did anything wrong?

Comment: this work for me too: git rm --cached .vscode/settings.json

Answer (score 43):

It's very simple to do, requiring no code. Follow these steps:

**1)** Navigate to VSCode's settings:
[image]

**2)** Next, navigate to `User Settings`, then go to `Extensions -> Git -> Enabled (property)` as shown:
[image]

*Make sure this checkbox is disabled.*

Comment: In my case Git missing from extensions, what i need to do? @George_E

Comment: @Gem I’m not exactly sure... Maybe your project doesn’t already have Git setup for it?

Comment: How can i set up Git in VS Code? screenshot : https://snag.gy/OhTBpR.jpg @George_E

Comment: @Gem Sorry I’m not sure, you’ll have to ask a question on that. My project originated from Xcode and I started Git from there. That’s why when doing part of it in VSCode, I wanted to disable Git so I didn’t have conflicts.

Answer (score 19):

Windows:

Go to File -> Preferences Settings (Or press Ctrl + ,)

[image]

Go to Extensions -> Git -> Uncheck "Enabled" (Or search "git.enabled" in the search box above)

[image]

Comment: In my case Git missing from Extension, what i need to do? @The One

Comment: Just go to settings.Json and Edit it

Comment: I can't find that option!

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio Code you can change your settings quite easily.

Once opened you have a 2 column window to choose from a set of standard options. The more extensions you install the longer this list of standard options becomes. There you can also choose from a set of GIT options.

Here is preview image of some of the preferences:

[image: preview of preferences]

Answer (score 1):

Just one addition to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33956083/10669875):

By default, Visual Studio Code also parsers `.gitignore` files, and avoids searching in "Git ignored" files, even if Git integration is disabled. To disable this feature and allow searching in all files, add the following line to your `settings.json` file:

```json
"search.useIgnoreFiles": false,
```

Answer (score 0):

> it is traversing all ~14000 files

I wonder if one can change one of the other settings in VSCode to affect what you are seeing without turning it off? Such as these scan ones:

[image]