# How can I disable the popup window that appears when I click on a SCM diff decoration in the editor gutter?

Tags: visual-studio-code, codelens

In Visual Studio Code I wish to permanently hide the window that pops up with an inline diff in my text editor. It appears after clicking on the blue bar next to the line numbers.

[image: window popup example]

Is there a setting to disable this?

I have disabled the codelens setting, but it doesn't resolve my problem.

Comment: if you want to disable it try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52337432/4807542
and if you want to hide it only try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60222758/4807542

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following in your settings.json file:

```json
"scm.diffDecorationsGutterAction": "none"
```

The description for that settings says:

> Controls the behavior of Source Control diff gutter decorations.