# How to prevent accidental clicking on gutter in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is a very annoying issue in vs code:

[image]

in case you want to collapse a section, you might accidentally click a blue rectangle, which pops up when you hover over the blue (or green) line

After you accidentally click the blue rectangle it shows changes history, like this:

[image]

Is there a way to disable this "quick diff" pop-up window containing the changes? Or make the buttons further apart? What are the **keywords** that may be helpful while googling this prolem?

This issue is present with all the extensions disabled.

Edit: i want to keep the gutters, just disable the changes history pop-up window

Also, there is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58746387/vscode-hide-inline-git-changes-in-window-popup-text-editor)

Comment: Here is the ticket about editor.contentLeftPadding as official setting. This setting will not only resolve usability but also visual issue. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135114 (20 or more likes are needed on the feature request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59031656/add-left-space-margin-padding-in-vs-code-editor-window-between-line-numbers-and), you can add some space between the editor and the gutters.

- Go to File->Preferences->Settings
- Click on the right top button to open settings as JSON
- Add the following to the json: `"editor.lineDecorationsWidth": 35,`

Comment: This is not working in 2021! But here is the ticket about editor.contentLeftPadding as official setting. This setting will not only resolve usability but also visual issue. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135114 (20 or more likes are needed on the feature request)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when this became available, but by setting 'SCM: Diff Decorations Gutter Action' to 'None', you can completely disable click actions on those diff-indications in the gutter:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you want to disable it try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52337432/4807542 and if you want to hide it only try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60222758/4807542 
Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your solution is to disable gutters alltogether. I am looking for a solution that keeps the gutters, but disables "the clicking actions"

Comment: you mean keep showing it but without the ability to click on it?

Comment: yes, exactly. Or make somehow possible not to click accidentally on the gutter while trying to collapse the section.