# How to remove SCM icon from VScode workspace?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I am currently learning to use git / github and I prefer to use only the command line so I thought about removing everything related to SCM from my workspace. Using the answers given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331338/remove-git-integrations-from-vscode/52337432), I already managed to deactivate GIT from my workspace (1) **but what I still can't get is to remove the workspace icon** (2).

[image]

**I know that you can right click + hide but I would like to know if there is any option to leave it defined in the settings.json file without using the visual form**

[image]

OBS: VScode version 1.47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right-click and select the option **hide**

[image]

Comment: Will there be some option to leave it defined in the settings.json file without using the visual form @Teste_Account

Comment: If you hide it will remain hidden, it is unknown for me settings for it.